# MySQL syntax variation

Tags: mysql

I am learning Php/MySQL from online tutorials (not that I expect you to watch it, but as a reference: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJ3tDQfJt4k)

I am using MySQL 5.5.27 through phpMyAdmin 3.5.2.2

In the tutorial, this code is given (and works):

```
INSERT INTO 'posts' ('title', 'contents') VALUES('this is the first post', 'Yes it is.')
```

However, I receive this error message:
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use..."

This syntax (which I found through trial and error) works for me:

```
INSERT INTO posts (title, contents) VALUES('this is the first post', 'Yes it is.')
```

I would like someone to explain why this is the case, and how to identify correct syntax - or to be linked to some documentation which would make this distinction comprehensible for a beginner. (I am unlikely to be able to follow the manual at this point in my learning.) Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: To specify table name use backticks  instead of single quote. i.e ) \`posts\` not 'post'...

Comment: Single quotes in SQL are for string literals, identifiers (such as table and column names) are not strings, they're identifiers. Identifiers are quoted with double quotes (standard), backticks (MySQL), or brackets (SQL Server AFAIK) depending on the database and how it is configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL identifiers (column and table names) are optionally encased by backticks "`", not single quotes. The video is a little blurry and I can see why you would mistake them.
Try:

```
INSERT INTO `posts` (`title`, `contents`) VALUES('this is the first post', 'Yes it is.')
```

Comment: Not blurry.  For watching the programming tutorials on YouTube, always select the high quality (480p or 720pHD) by selecting "Change Quality" icon under the video (5th from the left).  Learned it the hard way, as well, @GregoryTippett ;-)

Comment: @GregD Awesome. With stackoverflow, you learn WHILE($awakeExists){$newStuff++;} everyday!

Answer (score 0):

By default, identifiers can be escaped with backquotes, not single quotes. The default condition is due to the [**sql_mode**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sql-mode) mysqld starts with.

You could use double quotes if you configure [ANSI_QUOTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) for the [**sql_mode**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sql-mode).

I wrote about this in the DBA StackExchange : [**How to convert MySQL Keyword to normal column**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6487/877)